# In the context of Hillary saying she "owes penance" to L.F. de Rothschild, what does "owing penance" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, quotes, politics

In [this email](https://wikileaks.org/clinton-emails/emailid/1570) leaked by Wikileaks, Hillary Clinton asks [Rothschild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynn_Forester_de_Rothschild) to:

> Let me know what penance I owe you.

The only [definitions I can find](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/penance) for the word "penance" are religious terms that imply that one has sinned and must somehow repent or make up for it to God or clergy.

What is meant by "owing penance" to another (non-clerical) human being, in this context?

**Edit:** Since I've gotten some downvotes for this question, I wonder if those who downvoted could help me improve it by explaining why they did so. (E.G. poorly researched, unclear, off-topic, offensive, general reference, inaccurate assumptions, etc.) Although it's not required, it's always more helpful if downvotes come coupled with constructive feedback.

Comment: In the [skeptics question that prompted this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34728) you mentioned you were interested in whether the use of "penance" implied a "subservient tone", I think that'd be a good thing to include in this question. Certainly in British English, it would be normally, *except* in the context of old-fashioned upper-class letter writing where such styling was almost normal and expected even among social equals (e.g. signing letters "I remain forever your faithful servant"). It'd be interesting to see if that's also true for American "old money" society

Comment: As Gary describes, it's plain old hyperbole, likely used in a jocular sense.  If you're looking for a skeleton you're in the wrong closet.

Comment: @HotLicks Why would I be looking for skeletons? I'm looking for language related explanations regarding a peculiar, rarely used, type of wording.

Comment: Since I've gotten some downvotes for this question, I wonder if those who downvoted could help me improve it by explaining why they did so. (E.G. poorly researched, unclear, off-topic, offensive, general reference, inaccurate assumptions, etc.) Although it's not required, it's always more helpful if downvotes come coupled with constructive feedback.

Comment: I think the failure to comprehend simple hyperbole is perhaps at the root of the downvotes.  It tends to suggest that one does not *want* to understand, or is looking for a more sinister meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks Why would they think I do not comprehend simple hyperbole? You mean in the sense that I shouldn't even have needed to ask the question?

Comment: @HotLicks Or that I didn't want to understand Gary's answer? I actually tend to agree with Gary's answer, though I did ask him for another example of the phrase being used in that way. I would certainly also have asked for sources if someone suggested something "more sinister".

Comment: I still don't understand why you didn't understand it.  The first definition in your link is *a punishment undergone in token of penitence for sin*, and if you understand the metaphorical use of "sin" then "penance" can apply to any error on your part where you seek the forgiveness of the "wronged" party.

Comment: @HotLickWhat makes you think I didn't understand it? I was asking for a source or example of "owing penance" being used in a non-religious context. I often ask for sources to things. And the example in OP is a strange usage that I have never seen before. This is merely to improve the quality of answers. I was certainly not criticizing Gary's answer or saying that I disagreed. On the contrary, I said the answer "sounded good". Nor did I include any speculation about anything "sinister" anywhere.

Comment: You said *What is meant by "owing penance" to another (non-clerical) human being, in this context?*

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, I see. You're saying it was pretty obvious so there wouldn't have been a need to ask the question in the first place?

Comment: It's still unclear what you didn't understand.

Comment: @HotLicks I'll clarify, then: I didn't consider that this might be a hyperbole until it was suggested by others. That is true. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word is being used hyperbolically here.

Meaning:

> "How can I make amends?"

[ref: 'make amends'](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/make--amends)

You can clearly see a relationship between the word penance and the phrase "making amends" if you consider the transitive verb: -

> Expiate
>
> v.tr. To make amends or reparation for; atone for: expiate one's sins
>   by acts of penance.

ref: [Expiate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expiate)

Comment: Sounds like a good answer, but could you provide a source for "owing penance" being used in the place of "making amends" in a non-religious context? I'm not saying your answer is wrong, I just figure you could improve its quality by providing a source. All resources I have found on the word "penance" seem to offer only religious meanings.

Comment: Certainly, edited above.

Comment: I meant more of an example or source for "owing penance" being used in a non-religious context. *Expiate* can mean both religious (as in penance) and non-religious (as in "make ammends".) But what I meant was a source for "owing penance" itself being used in a non-religious context, not another phrase being used as such.

Comment: No I think the connection is clear, and I don't have any more time to spend right now! Good luck in your journey though :)